# Exception in RuntimeBroker on UWP app startup

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

C# UWP project with a native component in C++, targeting Windows 10 14393, Visual Studio 2019. Running the 32-bit build. On one machine (Windows 10 x64), it runs fine. On another machine (also Windows 10 x64), during startup, it pop up a JIT debugger window:

> "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in [204976] RuntimeBroker.exe."

and a choice of debuggers.

If you click "Cancel", the UWP app in question starts as it should. If you choose to debug, the exception is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFC1025362A (Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll) in RuntimeBroker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

EDIT: it crashes when the following fragment is executed:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ProductLicense> ld = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;
//Which of the ProdIDs are purchased?
bool[] Actives = ProdIDs.Select(
                pid => ld.ContainsKey(pid) && ld[pid].IsActive).ToArray();
```

The `ld` is not null, but when `ContainsKey` is called, the crash happens and the app throws an exception. The application is not on the store yet, so there are no in-app products registered. I don't expect this call to return anything sensible, but still, not cool.

Comment: If you click the "Cancel", will the project run well? In addition, the Runtime Broker application is responsible for checking whether there is a particular privilege for an App. It will check if an application is declaring all permissions and notifying user if it’s allowed or not. First, you could check if the permissions have been authorized.

Comment: The project runs well. The only checked capability is Internet (Client), that works as usual.

Comment: Judging by the second error message, the problem happens somewhere with the usage of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace, could you post some code which uses these APIs?

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: is `pid` null? What is the value of `ld.Count`?

Comment: `pid` is never null. It comes from `ProdIDs`, an array of nonblank strings. The crash happens after I call ld.ContainsKey(pid) for the first time, which then throws an exception.

Comment: Calling ld.Count causes the same exception.

Comment: You need to publish your app in the Microsoft Store for the [CurrentApp.LicenseInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.LicenseInformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to work. As a test, you can use [CurrentAppSimulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator) to get simulated license info.

Answer (score 0):

As Faywang said in comments, the app has to be published in the Microsoft Store for `LicenseInformation` to work. If it is already in the store, you might simply need to sign in to the store on the machine on which you are trying to debug.